# How do I display a link in a community self-registration controller error message?

Tags: apex, community

I am using the new Configurable Self Rego page for communities. 
I have successfully put in a new error message using Try & catch, but I want to make the url in the error message clickable.

```
catch (Exception e) {
        string message = e.getMessage();
        string LinkUrl = 
System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/c';
        if(message.equals('[User already exists.]')){
            throw new Auth.DiscoveryCustomErrorException ('User 
Already Exists, please go to login page. ' + LinkUrl );
        }else{

            throw new 
Auth.DiscoveryCustomErrorException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this a lightning community? if so, any reason why you didnt create the link client side, in your lightning component?

Comment: The configurable self rego only uses an apex class. There is no component.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using custom component for it, you can return a wrapper object having details of success and failure. It can contain list of errorMessages.
Create message as html, e.g. User 
Already Exists, please go to login page.

On lightning component, iterate over the error messages and show them using **aura:unescapedHtml** tag.